# Is there any benefit in installing a genuine auxiliary battery for my car?

Tags: mercedes-benz

The car in question is 2014 Mercedes E300 Hybrid (W212).
It has an Auxiliary battery in the trunk next to the main battery and I am getting an auxiliary battery malfunction on the dashboard. After some research it turns out it is sort of a consumable and it is not unexpected to need changing after 3 years.

The [genuine one](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Genuine-Mercedes-Benz-E-CLS-M-GLClass-Auxiliary-Battery-12V-12AH-200A/291659116419?hash=item43e83cef83:g:X6EAAOSwaMhZw34C) costs £75 or
I can get [VARTA YTX14-BS](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/YTX14-BS-AGM-Liquifix-Gel-Technology-VARTA-BMW-K1200S-Motorbike-Battery/192267219877?epid=1067455985&hash=item2cc404f3a5:g:0X4AAOSwzhVWsKt8) for £42
or
[Exide ETX14-BS](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ETX14-BS-Exide-Motorcycle-Battery-12V-12Ah-200CCA-With-Filling-Kit-/252817850290?_trksid=p2385738.m2548.l4275) for £37

Both non-genuine batteries have the exact same specs: Voltage, Amperage (CCA), amp hour and size.

The battery is used for some electronics in the car such as the Eco Start/Stop function and Break Hold functions.

My common sense tells me that there is no way the car would realise I have installed a non-genuine battery as the only connections are Positive and Negative terminals.

Are there any benefits in choosing the genuine one over the other brands?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I think you're going to get a lot of opinion on this, but really, IMHO, there's no reason to go back to MB for a battery unless you're a purest with deep pockets.

Comment: You will probably find that the MB battery is just one made by Bosch, Exide, Varta etc and re-badged anyway : MB purchase items in just like any other manufacturer : electronic components, wiper blades....... Get the one that meets the specs . it will be fine.

Comment: Some people genuinely appreciate the level of service at a luxury car dealership.  You're paying extra for that, and to have a trusted, easy to use warranty if the new battery dies prematurely.  If you can and want to do this yourself, then no, there is no reason at all to pay more for a name.